# Jpa table strategy - how to get the primary key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am using JPA table strategy to generate the primary key for the table.
This works fine.

There is a scenario where I need to have another column in the table with the same primary key ( this is an exception flow )
Since I cannot get the primary key unless the insertion is complete , is there any way I can map another column in the table to the same generated primary key before the insert happens .

Thanks

Lives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's much more common to reference an entity by its primary key, Hibernate also offers [NaturalIds](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/NaturalId.html).

The NaturalId is mapped to a unique column so that each entity can also be uniquely reference any this natural identifier.

You even have an API for [retrieving entities by the natural identifier](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#byNaturalId%28java.lang.Class%29).

So I think it's much more elegant to use the natural id for your task because it's consistent across all [entity state transitions](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-entity-state-transitions/).